# octoberCMS | Turf off backend redirect to secure protocol

Tags: octobercms, octobercms-backend

I discovered that when I turn OFF the debugging mode on my application,
`/config/app.php`

[image]

The backend starts using secure protocol... And I have problems with that because on some websites it's works well: (and on that example I really don't know why secure protocol is **valid**)

[image]

And with other websites I have big problems, bacause It's redirect to another pages... Here's an example:[image]

How can I turn the redirect to secure protocol with OFF debuging mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try set

```
'backendForceSecure' => false
```

in config/cms.php